# I am not able to use re module, my interpreter showing me error

Tags: python

My code is:

```
import re
s="An apple in a day."
print(re.search("in",s))
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\DELL\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/encodings/re.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/encodings/re.py", line 1, in <module>
    import re
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\encodings\re.py", line 3, in <module>
    re.search("is",s)
AttributeError: partially initialized module 're' has no attribute 'search' (most likely due to a circular import)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You name your file `re.py` so python confused which one to use when you call `import re`: your file or regexp library.
Try to rename your file to something else and not to choose other library names.